# How do i update my Bio on MYSQL(database)?

Tags: php

Update page.

```
<?php


        if(isset($_FILES['profile']) === true){
            if(empty($_FILES['profile']['name'])===true){
                echo 'Please Choose a file';
            }else{
                $allowed = array ('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
                $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

                if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed)===true){
                    change_profile_image(($_SESSION['accts_id']), $file_temp, $file_extn);
                    header('Location'. $current_file);
                }else{
                    echo 'Incorret file type. Allowed: ';
                    echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                }
            }
        }




        $firstname = getuserfield('firstname');
        $profile = getuserfield('Profile');

        if(empty($profile ===false)){
            echo '<img src="', $profile,'" alt="',$firstname,'\'s Profile Image">';
        }

        if(isset($_POST['textarea'])){
            $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];
            if(!empty($_POST['textarea'])){

            change_bio_details($_SESSION['accts_id'], $textarea);
            header('Location'. $current_file);
        }else
        {
            echo 'Please enter data';
        }

        }

    ?>
```

functionpage.

```
function change_profile_image($accts_id, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
    $file_path ='imageuploaded/profile/'. substr (md5(time()), 0,10). '.'. $file_extn; 
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    $sql = "UPDATE `accts` SET `Profile` ='". mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE `id` =" . (int)$accts_id; 
    mysql_query($sql);
}

function change_bio_details($accts_id, $textarea){
    $sql = "UPDATE `accts` SET `Bio` ='".$textarea."' WHERE `id = ". (int)$accts_id;
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: and where's the problem? (apart from that missing \` in the very last 'update.... where id=')

Answer (score 0):

first create input file then

get that file and update your MySQL with url of new image

if you want to see the code comment here I can explain it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was just missing ` on my last update. its already working. I'm so stupid. Thank you again.

Comment: congrats bro I hope be happy and lucky all time

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo in your last update-query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `accts` SET `Bio` ='".$textarea."' WHERE `id = ". (int)$accts_id;
```

You're missing one ` after 'id':

```
....WHERE `id` = "....
```

Comment: Ya, I didn't notice it. Thank you very much.